# Как синхронно воспроизвести несколько видеофайлов с помощью DirectShow?

Tags: c#, видео, directshow

Есть несколько видеофайлов (снималось одно событие с разных видеокамер). Я пытаюсь сделать видеоплеер для синхронного (вплоть до долей секунд) их воспроизведения на базе directshow. Поскольку я пишу на C#, использую библиотеку DirectShowLib-2005. Сейчас я запускаю их независимо друг от друга и через некоторое время они естественно рассинхронизируются. Существуют ли в Directshow инструменты, обеспечивающие синхронизацию графов? Если да то какие? Также буду благодарен если подскажите решение на базе других библиотек.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

И видео и аудио можно синхронизировать исключительно точно посредством использования собственной реализации часов и [`IReferenceClock`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/strmif/nn-strmif-ireferenceclock) интерфейса в частности.

Собственные часы передаются независимым графам и воспроизведение синхронизируется с часами. Вы же уже вольны корректировать ход этих часов как вам заблагорассудится.